# How to properly implement Inheritance in EF, with performance in mind

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

My app has `Posts` and `Flags`.  Both of these have `Responses`, which have `Comments`.

```
Post
   Response
      Comment
Flag
   Response
      Comment
```

I'm trying to model this in EF as simply and properly as possible, but I'm not sure if I'm going overboard here with inheritance.  This is what I have:

```
public class Post {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostResponse> Responses { get; private set; }
}

public class Flag {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int FlagId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FlagResponse> Responses { get; private set; }
}
```

I wanted to use just generic `Response` here, but then my Response class would need to account for both a parent `Flag` and `Post`.  Adding both `ParentPostId` and `ParentFlagId` to the same class seemed like a dirty way to handle it, especially taking the relationships mapping into account.  So I split Responses up:

**High level Message:**

```
// Comments, Posts, Responses all have these properties
public abstract class Message {
    [Required]
    public int PosterId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Poster { get; set; }
    public string RawContent { get; set; }            
}
```

**Responses:**

```
public abstract class Response : Message {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
}
// will be used by Posts only
public class PostResponse : Response {
    [Required]
    public int ParentPostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
// will be used by Flags only
public class FlagResponse : Response {
    [Required]
    public int ParentFlagId { get; set; }
    public virtual Flag Flag { get; set; }
}
```

So see, then I had to account for the difference in Comments:

**Comments:**

```
public abstract class Comment : Message {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
}
// will be used by PostResponses only
public class PostComment : Comment {
    [Required]
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public virtual PostResponse Response { get; set; }
}
// will be used by FlagResponses only
public class FlagComment : Comment {
    [Required]
    public int ResponseId { get; set; }
    public virtual PostResponse Response { get; set; }
}
```

So I've fattened up my schema and now my FluentAPI codefirst configurations are going to get tricky, but my logic can now easily distinguish between types and the data is normalized.

It *feels* less smelly than packing everything into a single model, but I'm not sure if this is even close to a best practice, especially with performance concerns.  Performance is the highest priority with the design.

**Update**

After spending nearly the entire afternoon on trying to implement TPH inheritance with Code-First, I've thrown my hands up.  See this question:

[EF Inheritance and Foreign Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446856/ef-inheritance-and-foreign-keys?lq=1)

So I think the cheapest and post performant solution would be for me to add optional FK Ids to the Response object - one for FlagId and the other for PostId.  Beef up my validation a bit, be the opposite of normalized, but stay away from complicating my schema and introducing more joins for queries in TPC or TPT, and avoid the hating-myself that comes with TPH in this scenario.  I think what I'm doing is brute-force TPH anyways.

I'll keep this up in case anyone has any suggestions or in case this can spare anyone else from the anguish I've experienced today.